# Downloading data as CSV in Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I have an array of objects like shown below.

```
var csvArray = [
        {
            Symbol: "AAPL",
            Company: "Apple Inc.",
            Price: "132.54"
        },
        {
            Symbol: "INTC",
            Company: "Intel Corporation",
            Price: "33.45"
        },
        {
            Symbol: "GOOG",
            Company: "Google Inc",
            Price: "554.52"
        },
    ];
```

I followed [this](https://halistechnology.com/2015/05/28/use-javascript-to-export-your-data-as-csv/) tutorial and tried to download it as CSV file.

I did exactly the same but I cant download the file. The `CSV` file data is being generated but it can't be downloaded. The codes I used are given below.

```
function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
  var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

  data = args.data || null;
  if (data == null || !data.length) {
      return null;
  }

  columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
  lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

  keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

  result = '';
  result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
  result += lineDelimiter;

  data.forEach(function(item) {
      ctr = 0;
      keys.forEach(function(key) {
          if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

          result += item[key];
          ctr++;
      });
      result += lineDelimiter;
  });
  // alert(result);
  return result;
}

function downloadCSV(args) {
  var data, filename, link;

  var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
      data: csvArray
  });

  // alert(csv);

  if (csv == null) return;

  filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

  if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
      csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
  }
  // alert(filename);
  data = encodeURI(csv);
  alert(data);


  link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', data);
  // link.setAttribute('href', encodeURI(data));
  link.setAttribute('download', filename);
  link.click();
}
```

The `data` variable finally after `encodeURI` have the following result

[image]
What is wrong with this code? Why is it failing to download the file?

How it can be fixed such that I can download the data as `CSV` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've experienced this problem before and the solution I found was to use Blobs to download the CSV. Essentially, you turn the csv data into a Blob, then use the URL API to create a URL to use in the link, eg:

```
let csvData = str;
let a: any = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
document.body.appendChild(a);
let blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv' });
let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.href = url;
a.download = 'visitors.csv';
a.click();
```